# Insertion on Asp.Net Mvc Failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

On my asp.net mvc project, the table data will be displayed on a grid view using Index Method.
    After doing Insertion, it would redirect to Index using RedirectToAction. But for the First time, the new row is getting added to the grid. When tried second time, the insertion is not possible. 
    But if i reload the page using browser reload again, for the first time only insertion takes place. Please help me to resolve this issue.

When I tried to debug, "the process has been changed since the last step" takes place. So, the values during the first debug also coming for insertion on second time which break the operation. Give Solution pls..

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        X_DEVEntities Entity = new X_DEVEntities();
        var outPut=Entity.Model.ToList();
        return View(outPut);
    }

    public ActionResult Insert(Model modelData)
    {
        X_DEVEntities Entity = new X_DEVEntities();
        modelData.create_user_id = "ty";
        modelData.last_mod_dtm = DateTime.Now;
        modelData.last_mod_user_id = "gdf";            
        Entity.Model.Add(modelData);            
        Entity.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");           

    }
```

Comment: when you are inserting data? on any button click?

Comment: yes, I m using kendo ui. On that Add New Item ,I do insertion.

Comment: What does _"the insertion is not possible"_ mean?

Comment: on second insertion, it tries to insert the values that we tried on first insertion. So it shows error of values already exits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On second insertion you are getting error because on each insertion you'll have same `create_user_id` and `last_mod_user_id` based upon the your Insert method you posted.
I'm guessing it should be something like this

```
public ActionResult Insert(Model modelData)
    {
        X_DEVEntities Entity = new X_DEVEntities();//try not to do this in your Insert method, rather have a constructer where you place this instantiation.
        Entity.yourTableName.UserId=modelData.create_user_id;//(UserId should be the field where you want to place the username you get from the view)
        modelData.last_mod_dtm = DateTime.Now;
        Entity.yourTableName.LastModUserId=modelData.last_mod_user_id;//again LastModUserId is the field where you want to save your modelData.last_mod_user_id in table.       
        Entity.Model.Add(modelData);            
        Entity.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");           

    }
```

Comment: Absolutely. You are trying to use the same primary key for second insertion

Comment: When I tried to debug, the process has been changed since the last step takes place. So, the values during the first debug also coming for insertion on second time which break the operation. Give Solution pls..

Comment: For me normally in those situation, it works when I refresh the database or some related folders, files, from solution explorer. Or close the visual studio, and try again. Refresh the application and see if it works.

Comment: I m using entity framework in my project. Pls look at my view heading code below
@model IEnumerable<KendoUIMvcApplication1.Models.ModelData>

Comment: That really doesn't make any sense to just give out which model you are using. try and ask new question again with the Model, controller and view, also may be the context file with which you create tables. That will help you getting better answers. Also, accept the answer if it helped in that particular situation.

Comment: yes you are right with all respect, but how can i avoid coming the first request of insertion values as thread on second time. This is the problem.